# CreateJs - Controlling timeline playhead with click & drag

Tags: javascript, movieclip, createjs

First time posting here, hope I'm doing this right :) I am trying to create a 360 spin in Adobe Animate with createJS, using a sequence of images embedded in a MovieClip. I have managed to get control of the timeline playhead using the code below:-

```
var start_x;
var startFrame;
var changeDistance;
var travelDistance;

this.threeSixty.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown.bind(this));
this.threeSixty.addEventListener("pressup", onMouseUp.bind(this));

function onMouseDown(e) {
    start_x = e.stageX;
    startFrame = this.threeSixty.timeline.position;
    this.threeSixty.addEventListener("pressmove", onMouseMove.bind(this));
}

function onMouseUp(e) {
    this.threeSixty.removeEventListener("pressmove", onMouseMove.bind(this));
}

function onMouseMove(e) {
    var changeDistance = e.stageX-start_x;
    var travelDistance = startFrame+changeDistance;

    if (travelDistance > this.threeSixty.timeline.duration){
        this.threeSixty.gotoAndStop(travelDistance % this.threeSixty.timeline.duration);
    }else if (travelDistance < 0){
        this.threeSixty.gotoAndStop (this.threeSixty.timeline.duration + (travelDistance % threeSixty.timeline.duration));
    } else {
    this.threeSixty.gotoAndStop(travelDistance);
    }
}
```

The problem is, when you click and drag the image along the X axis, the image sequence only moves forward/backwards by a single frame, as opposed to continuing the image sequence until the either mouse has stopped moving, or the mouse click is released. Any ideas where I might be going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Any chance you need to round/floor the number? Do you have a working sample to share?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Lanny. In the end I added the eventListeners to the stage as opposed to the MovieClip itself, and used 'stagemousemove' as opposed to 'pressmove'. This fixed the problem. I'm still none the wiser why 'pressmove' wouldn't work, I can only assume it was conflicting with the 'mousedown' event. But all fixed now, thank you.